# How Can I update a particular row in numpy matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, reinforcement-learning

Here I am trying to update a specific row of my numpy matrix but it is acting a bit weird

```
tpm1=np.array([[1,0, 0, 0, 0],[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],[1,0, 0, 0, 0],[1,0, 0, 0, 0],[1,0, 0, 0, 0]])
tpm1[1,:]=0.15*tpm1[1,:]
[[1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0]]
```

Output is given as

```
[[1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0]]
```

But I expect [0.15,0,0,0,0] in the second row. I am not sure what's happening here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare the dtype as float when making your array:

```
tpm1=np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],[1,0, 0, 0, 0],[1,0, 0, 0, 0],[1,0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=float)
```

Alternatively, you can make one of the values 1.0 or 0.0 when declaring the array, e.g.:

```
tpm1=np.array([[1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],[1,0, 0, 0, 0],[1,0, 0, 0, 0],[1,0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

This will automatically set the array to dtype float.